# Pulling out a function from an integral. When is this allowed?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, partial-derivative

If I have a function which does not depend on the variable which is the integrating variable, can I pull that function out? That is, suppose I have $\int g(x,t)f(u_i - u(x,t))du_i$. Can I pull out the $g(x,t)$?

What about for when I have this: $\int \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t) f(u_i - u(x,t))du_i$? I know that by Leibniz's rule I can pull out the $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$, but I do not know if I am allowed to pull out the entire term $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t)\int f(u_i - u(x,t))du_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a valid step. You can think of
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(x,t)$$
as a constant in terms of $u_i$.

Comment: To clarify, my first suggestion is also valid? That indeed $\int g(x,t) f(u_i - u(x,t))du_i = g(x,t)\int f(u_i - u(x,t))du_i$ as $g(x,t)$ is seen as a constant in terms of $u_i$.

Comment: Yes. This is a "more complicated" version of the well-known property $$\int C\cdot f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = C\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ where $C$ is a constant (in terms of $x$).

Comment: What if I had $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}g(x,u_i, t)$ ?

Comment: *In general* you can not pull *this* function out because it depends on $u_i$.